# Formatting T-SQL in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

According to this Microsoft document:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

I am supposed to be able to use ctrl+K then ctrl+D to format my SQL documents in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 but when I use that combo I get the error:

> The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format
>   Document) which is not currently available.

I am trying to make modifications to an existing SQL document that has no formatting to it at all which makes it extremely difficult to read. Does anyone know how to make the Format Document command available so I can have SQL format this code for me?

Comment: I think the statement `Available only in the text editor` is the tech writer's way of saying "not the query editor" without explicitly calling out the negative

Comment: @billinkc I don't think that's quite right. [The text editor is the "query editor" used for both Transact-SQL and XML](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FtL6D.png), it just isn't really a query editor when it's dealing with XML. I think the documentation is a bit over-promising, and [I commented as such on the Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=496617).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The keyboard combination you're after (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) is for "formatting" - but not to the extent you seem to expect. It is not a prettifier, it is just used to insert correct spacing and tabs as found in `Tools > Options >  Text Editor > Transact-SQL > General/Tabs` - so if you highlight a portion of text and hit the keyboard combination, it is supposed to convert tabs to 4 spaces (if you've selected insert spaces), apply the type of indenting you've specified, etc.

This option is NOT intended to make code more readable - this is not functionality that Management Studio currently offers natively. Though there are several 3rd party options - some are external to Management Studio, like:

- [Simple-Talk's SQL Prettifier](http://extras.sqlservercentral.com/prettifier/prettifier.aspx)
- [Poor SQL](http://poorsql.com/) (which [Thomas suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45052/1186))

And there are add-ins as well for various levels of formatting assistance within the editor:

- [Red-Gate's SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/features)
- [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=4)
- [ApexSQL's Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx)
- [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-format-sql-document)
- [dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) (which [Robert suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45063/1186))

Now, the reason you are getting the message...

> The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format Document) which is not currently available.

...is because SSMS has mapped that key combination to a different context. The way you *should* be able to "fix" this - again, it still wouldn't do what you want it to do, even if the "fix" worked - is by doing the following:

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`
2. Place your cursor into the `Press shortcut keys:` box
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
4. Change the `Shortcut currently used by:` drop-down from `DataWarehouse Designer` to `Text Editor`

   [image]
5. Press OK

Now, this is *supposed* to map the keyboard combination to the text editor, but Management Studio reverts it after hitting OK (you will continue to get the error message. So, I think the problem is that the documentation believes this functionality exists, but Management Studio knows better and simply doesn't offer it (and Microsoft will likely write this off as a bug in the documentation, and correct it, rather than a shortcoming in the tool). There may be hope in the future but, for now, [this is a known and largely ignored issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=496617). You'll note that the `Formatting` tab that [the documentation refers to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(SQL.110).aspx) is simply not present (though it is there for XML, where the keyboard combination does work). The documentation should probably state:

> Applies the indenting and space formatting for the language specified on the **Formatting** pane of the language in the **Text Editor** section of the **Options** dialog. Available only in the text editor ***and only for certain languages***.

Another way to get an idea of what type of formatting options SSMS offers natively is to go to `Tools > Customize > Commands > Edit > Add Command... > Format` and look at the list of possible commands there. Nothing that indicates there is any knowledge of the actual language, so it wouldn't know where to insert line breaks or add additional indents or assist with parentheses etc.

[image]

If you want language-specific formatting to make existing T-SQL code more readable, you won't get much from SSMS, and you'll need to seek other options.

Comment: I experienced the same symptoms and behavior that were described by the OP as well as Aaron in SSMS 2016; however, I was able to get it to work properly.  The key was removing all commands bound to `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D` first using the `Remove` button, then follow Aaron's four-step program for binding the keyboard, as defined above (`Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`).

Here's a screenshot of what my `Options` dialog box looks like, once everything is setup: https://pasteboard.co/GDYkh3h.jpg .

Comment: I'm not at all certain why this comment isn't listed as an answer since it fricking works for me by doing what you said.

Answer (score 12):

I don't believe this is possible in SSMS.  There was a [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=496617) opened up for this feature.

What I personally like to use for poorly formatted SQL code is the web application on [Poor SQL](http://poorsql.com/).  It does a really nice job of formatting SQL code to your specifications.  Even generates HTML if you so desire.  I don't use the SSMS plug-in or any other deliverables they advertise, I always just hop on the site to do the quick formatting and then copy/paste right into SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Poor SQL.  Gonna keep that one tucked in my back pocket for sure!

Comment: Another good one (also useful for formatting code for blogs) is [Simple-Talk's SQL Prettifier](http://extras.sqlservercentral.com/prettifier/prettifier.aspx).

Comment: So even though Microsoft's document says it can format, SSMS can not?

Comment: Poor SQL also has a plug in for Notepad++.  Not sure why you wouldn't use the SSMS plug-in though.  It works great now that they finally made it work with SSMS 2012+.

Answer (score 6):

Install an add-on that does this. I use the Free Edition of SQL Complete: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/ which offers some *basic* SQL formatting functionality. It integrates with SSMS and uses Ctrl + K, D.

Comment: free online version http://www.sql-format.com/

Answer (score 2):

[SqlSmash](http://sqlsmash.com) is a commercial tool that lets you format your SQL (and much more) in SSMS 2012 and 2014. The default keyboard shortcut is (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D).
Disclaimer: I am the developer behind it.

Comment: Please add that the tool is not free.

Comment: There is a free community version.